# How to check if a construct of a class exists?

Tags: php, constructor, exists

Is there a function/method to check if a constructor exists in some class? I tried with the function_exists() method/function, but it looks like it doesn't work:

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Construct loaded.<br />';

        if (function_exists('__construct'))
            echo 'Function exists.';
        else
            echo 'Function doesn\'t exists.';
    }

}

new Test;
```

**UPDATE (thanks to all, this one works):**

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Construct loaded.<br />';
    }

}

$t = new Test;

if (method_exists($t, '__construct'))
    echo 'Function exists.';
else
    echo 'Function doesn\'t exists.';
```

**UPDATE #2**

because i need this before i create a new object, i ended up with this piece of code (i've added it just in case someone in the future will read this):

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Construct loaded.<br />';
    }

}

//$t = new Test;

if (method_exists('Test', '__construct'))
    echo 'Function exists.';
else
    echo 'Function doesn\'t exists.';
```

Comment: function_exists is checking for the existence of a __global  function__, not a class method.... try using [method_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

Comment: Because `function_exists('__construct')` is checking for functions, not class methods.

Comment: I guess this is only an example, but I do hope you're not checking for the existence of a constructor inside of itself...?!

Comment: @deceze no... it's just for this example. Else it would make no sense. :D

Comment: @Mark Baker thank you! It's working. Post you comment as an answer if you want... I will select it as my answer as you posted the first comment with the right solution.

Comment: Why was the question down voted? Comment please.

Comment: @tastro I guess because it shows no research effort at all.

Comment: @kapa should i write in my question: I googled, but found only `class_exists()` and `function_exists()` but didn't find `method_exists()` because i searched for the keyword "function" instead of "method". Sorry... It happens. Anyways... I don't care... No point it in anyways... :)

Comment: @tastro If you found `function_exists`, and checked the manual (of course you did), there is a See Also section that always contains some useful stuff.

Comment: @kapa i know... Looks like i red it all to fast or something. I must have missed that one. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) instead:

```
if (method_exists(self, '__construct')) {

}
```

`self` being `__CLASS__` or `Test` class in your case.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you can also use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstructor.php) :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have never used `ReflectionClass` before :)

Comment: As Mark Baker didn't post his answer as an answer, i voted yours as my accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @mTorres thanks! Good to know that i have more options... But for now i will go with `method_exists()`.

Comment: Oh, and going for completenes: ```is_callable('classname::__construct', true)``` should work too :-)

Comment: @mTorres: are the search engines too overpowered? :)